# How to get the selected tab panel element in Jquery UI Tabs?

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

The problem. I have multiple tab, their content is loaded via ajax, so the div id's of tabs' panels are assigned dynamically. I have a form in one, ajaxified by [this jquery plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) by a callback function bound to tabs.load event I pass it one parameter, the ui.panel, so that the ajaxForm() knows the target where to load result:

```
function initAjaxForms(loadtab)
{
   $('form').ajaxForm({target:loadtab, success:initAjaxForms});
}
```

This works fine, EXCEPT when I submit the form and PHP returns it as not valid, I cannot ajaxify it anymore (of course, the function is called with no loadtab parameter). the perfect solution would be to have more options to tabs so that i can do something like this:

```
function initAjaxForms()
{
   var selected = $('tabs').tabs('option', 'selectedpanel');
   $('form').ajaxForm({target:selectedpanel, success:initAjaxForms});
}
```

but this is obviously not it. Any ideas?

Comment: Replace 'selectedpanel' with 'active'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Select the .ui-tabs-panel that isn't hidden with .ui-tabs-hide:

```
var selectedPanel = $("#tabs div.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)");
```

Comment: Should be updated to: var selectedPanel = $("#tabs div.ui-tabs-panel:visible");

Comment: I was using this ':visible' trick for a while but I changed it to use '.ui-tabs-panel[aria-hidden=false]' because ':visible' is not reliable on IE8 and I could finally reproduce a bug that was reported by NewRelic where tabs.find('.ui-tabs-panel:visible') would return no element when clearly one of the tabs was visible. That doesn't happen in other browsers I've tested but since ':visible' is not reliable on IE8, I'll keep using ".ui-tabs-panel[aria-hidden=false]" for now.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore with jQuery 1.9+. Tyler Long's solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 12):

Maybe jqueryUI has changed, the accepted answer does not work for me. Here is what works:

```
$("#tabs div.ui-tabs-panel[aria-hidden='false']")
```

Comment: Excellent hint! Works like a charm with jQuery 1.9.1! Man you saved my day, dude!

Comment: thanks tyler,,this one works in 1.11...i've been pulling my hair off in the pass few days...darn

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured it out with a little hack, but I sense this is not a perfect solution:

```
function initAjaxForms()
{
    var selected = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
    var selectedtab = '#tabs > div:eq('+selected+')';
    var selectedtabelement = $(selectedtab).get(0);

    $('form').ajaxForm({ target:selectedtabelement, success:initAjaxForms});

}
```

anyone with better idea?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this very problem, and whilst this is an old question, it's the one that led me to this answer, which works:

```
var selectedPanel = $("#yw1 div.ui-tabs-panel:not(:has(.ui-tabs-hide))");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getSelectedTab(tabID){
    return $(tabID).find($(tabID+" .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-selected a").attr('href'));
}
var selectedPanel = getSelectedTab('#tabs');
```

This one will get you the object of the selected tab pane.

Answer (score 1):

Here is more simpler version:

```
function getSelectedTab(tabID){
   return $(tabID).find("[aria-expanded=true]");
}

var selectedPanel = getSelectedTab('#tabs');
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active you can do this:

```
var activeTab = this.$tabs.tabs("option", "active");
_this.$tabs.find(">div")[activeTab]
```