# ajaxSubmit into current jQuery Tab

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I know how to grab the index, but that doesn't appear to be what I need to post into the tab itself.

This is a continuation, but different question, from my previous post:  [Submiting jQuery form results back into dynamic tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349005/submiting-jquery-form-results-back-into-dynamic-tab/13349754#13349754)

My tab form is submitting now with 100% success, internal to my jQuery validate, but I want my reply to appear in the tab it came from.

At the end of my jQuery validation I have:

```
 submitHandler: function(form) {

 var thisTab = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected'); // what index are we?

 var options = {
     target: '#thisTab',

 };
 $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
 return false;
 }
```

It's close, but what I'm doing is actually grabbing the index of the selected tab, this does not appear to be what I need for the ajaxSubmit to post into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to set target to thisTab, but you are setting target as a jQuery selection string `#thisTab`,

this means target is the element with id "thisTab".

[From Jquery Form Plugin API](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object)

> **target**
>
> Identifies the element(s) in the page to be updated with the
>   server response. This value may be specified as a jQuery selection
>   string, a jQuery object, or a DOM element. Default value: null

So you should set `thisTab` as the target.

## Update :

The main problem is that you are trying to set tab as target element, you should set the selectedPanel as target.

```
 submitHandler: function(form) {

 var thisPanel = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selectedPanel'); // what index are we?

 var options = {
     target: thisPanel,

 };
 $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
 return false;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to come back and mark this.  While you answer did not solve the issue directly, it lead me to the answer I described below.  Therefore, it still solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, maybe I wasn't clear and I'm not explaining it.

What I want is for the output of update.cfm to be shown in the same dynamic tab body that held the details I just updated.  I tried what you suggested and all it does when I hit submit is blink.  It does submit, I can use firebug to see the post and response, but the response is not shown.  So I do want the tab as the target.

What you did do however is show me a new term "selectedPanel" that I did not know, and that lead me to this post which I had not seen before:  [How to get the selected tab panel element in Jquery UI Tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331335/how-to-get-the-selected-tab-panel-element-in-jquery-ui-tabs)

And that led me to make the following change:

```
 submitHandler: function(form) {

 var selectedPanel = $("#tabs div.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)");

 var options = {
 target: selectedPanel

 };
 $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
 return false;
 }
```